# Twilio SMS not working via ASP.NET MVC C# web deployed to Web Server (but works fine in local test environment)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, static, twilio

I had a very strange situation where SMS messages sent via Twilio were working when my team tested it in the local host ASP.NET MVC & C# testing environment (VS2022).

But the deployed version on the web server throws an initialization error and the SMS is never sent.

The code is in a static class called `Common`. After hours of attempts, I discovered (to my horror) that Twilio does not properly initialize from a static class when running on the web server. But it works fine in the local host test environment.

My solution was to change the `Common` class from a static class to a dynamic public IDisposable class and remove all references to 'static'. How that is done is so fundamental and verbose that I don't feel the need to explain it.

I know, I know... why (the hell) was I using a static class in a webpage? Because I stole a bunch of working code from an old WinForms app and it was working just fine for everything else.

Here's how you call a dynamic IDisposable class called `Common`:

```
        Common thisCommon = new Common();
        thisCommon.Method();
        thisCommon.Dispose();
```

After this terrible experience, I decided to NEVER ever use static classes in C# / ASP.NET MVC web pages ever again. It's not reliable in all situations. And, to be frank, it probably was a terrible idea in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I said above, you shouldn't be so lazy and use a static class in an MVC 5.0 C#  web app environment. Make it a dynamic iDisposible class and things will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem I faced, but I used the below code before calling MessageResource.Create function TwilioClient

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

See if that works for you.